# Starting with Java

Tags: java, startup

So I am trying to start with Java (as in, trying to get the dang thing to accept code). I download all the needed things (the SDK) from Java and such, but when it gets to the point where I have to do "javac" in Command Prompt to compile the notepad file, I just get the message saying that there is no command called "javac".

Anybody wanna share some insight?

Comment: Have you set your PATH environment variable to point to the location where you installed `javac.exe`?

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Car is to Carpet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the environment variable PATH: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml.

Also I recommend using an IDE such as [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) or [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). They make it much easier when starting off in java, plus when getting into advanced projects with many classes, they help greatly.

Comment: I understand [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) is a good IDE for beginning Java programmers.

Comment: While this method will work, I'd recommend following the method suggested by Casey as it is much more maintainable to use a JAVA_HOME variable in your path.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the path to your java compiler for it to be found when you use the command prompt. [This page explains how](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the following environment variable:,

`JAVA_HOME` to point to the root of your java installation e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java`

than append the following to your `PATH` environment variable:

`;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

than you will be able to use `java` and `javac` from the command line.

Also see [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726962.aspx) article from Microsoft on setting environment variables if your not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm surprised your the only one who mentioned setting the JAVA_HOME variable. This is much more maintainable than the accepted alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Java bin directory (where javac.exe is located, assuming you're on Windows), to your system PATH.

Right click on "My Computer", go to Environment Variables, and add the bin directory where Java is installed to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have the java bin directory on your path. So, on windows, if installed at c:\java, and bin is c:\java\bin  (normally you have version number, jre vs sdk, etc), you will need to add that to your PATH environment variable. set PATH=c:\java\bin;%PATH%  -- you could do this in a setlocal/endlocal block or set it permanatly for your machine.

Also, the JRE may not have javac -- you may need to dowload the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with java by typing 'javac' at the command line satisfy my mother's definition of the phrase 'starting with' ... as in,

"Don't start with me, buddy."

You are likely to end up with a punch in the nose.

For your own sanity, pick one of Eclipse, or NetBeans, or IntelliJ, or the other popular IDEs, and start from there.